# Manually create `enumerate`-labels

Tags: enumerate, itemize, labels

In the statement of a mathematical lemma, I have two similar statements that are supposed to make up statement *a*) and *b*) of the lemma. However, since I want to align the similarities properly, after some fiddling around with `\makemathbox` I have resorted to simply using `alignedat`-environments. So my current code looks like this:

```
For all
$\begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
    t, t' & \in c^+\:\text{with}\ & t & \leq t'\colon & \ldots\\
    r, r' & \in c^-\:\text{with}\ & r & \leq r'\colon & \ldots
\end{alignedat}$
```

**Edit:** This is how I got so far, which is *almost* what I want:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{
    label=\textit{\alph*}\textup{)},
}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\begin{document}
        \newlength\myleftmargin\setlength\myleftmargin\leftmargin
        \newlength\myitemindent\setlength\myitemindent\itemindent
        \begin{lemma}For all

        \vspace\partopsep%
        \noindent\hspace\myleftmargin%
        \begin{enumerate*}[mode=unboxed]%
            $\begin{alignedat}[t]{4}
                \makebox[\myitemindent][r]{\item\hspace{\labelsep}}&&%
                t, t' & \in c^+\:\text{with}\ & t & \leq t'\colon & 
                \ldots
                \\[\dimexpr\itemsep+\parsep\relax]%
                %
                \makebox[\myitemindent][r]{\item\hspace{\labelsep}}&&%
                r, r' & \in c^-\:\text{with}\ & r &\leq r'\colon &
                \ldots
                \\[\dimexpr\itemsep+\parsep\relax]%
                %
                \makebox[\myitemindent][r]{\item\hspace{\labelsep}}&&%
                \mathmakebox[\widthof{$r, r'$}][l]{\mathrm{S}}
            \end{alignedat}$
            \end{enumerate*}
        \end{lemma}
        \begin{proof}\strut
        \begin{enumerate}
            \item Some argument;
            \item Some argument.\qedhere
        \end{enumerate}
        \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: Output of the above code]

However, if you zoom in, you'll notice that the labels in the statement and the enumeration in the proof are not perfectly aligned. Also, you'll notice that the capital "S" are not aligned. How to do this right?

Comment: What's `\im` for?

Comment: @egreg Removed everything not necessary for making clear what I want.

Comment: Now it is very different from the original. Please, roll back and add the definition for `\im`.

Comment: @Bubaya: What would help here is if you can draft up what you want the output to look like using some other application. Currently all you're stating is that "this is ugly", but that's subjective. Clearly define what you're after and we can work with that.

Comment: @Werner: The bottom code produces what is to be achieved. By "this is ugly", I mean that the TeX code (and not the output) is bad style since it is hard to maintain if I decide that enumerations in a lemma-environment should have a different appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution myself: obstructions for proper spacing were:

1. That `theorem`-environments redefine all lengths involved in printing enumerations,
2. `alignedat` introduces additional spacing.

The following code seems to do the correct thing, although I do not want why I need the additional length `\myspacewidth`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsthm,amsmath}
\usepackage{printlen,array}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate]{%
    label=\textit{\alph*}\textup{)}%
}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\newlength\mytopsep\mytopsep\topsep
\newlength\myleftmargin\myleftmargin\leftmargin
\newlength\mylabelsep\mylabelsep\labelsep
\newlength\myitemsep\myitemsep\itemsep
\newlength\myparsep\myparsep\parsep
\newlength\myspacewidth%
\newenvironment{enumalign}[1]{%
    \par%
    \vspace\mytopsep%
    \noindent%
    \let\olditem\item%
    \settowidth\myspacewidth{{} {}}%
    \renewcommand\item{\llap{\strut\olditem\hspace{\dimexpr\mylabelsep-\myspacewidth\relax}}}%
    \newcommand\nl{\\[\dimexpr\myitemsep+\myparsep\relax]}%
    \begin{enumerate*}[mode=unboxed]$%
        \begin{array}{@{\hspace{\myleftmargin}}r@{}*{#1}{r@{}>{{}}l@{\ }}}%
}{%
        \end{array}%
    $\end{enumerate*}%
}
\begin{document}
        \begin{lemma}
        For all
            \begin{enumalign}{3}
                \item &
                t, t' & \in c^+\:\text{with} & 
                t & \leq t'\colon & 
                a &= b
                \nl%
                \item & r, r' & \in c^-\:\text{with} & r &\leq r'\colon &
            \end{enumalign}
        \end{lemma}
        \begin{proof}\strut
            \begin{enumerate}
                \item Some argument;
                \item Some argument.
            \end{enumerate}
        \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

which yields

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'll use the original code, with a mocked up definition for `\im`.

The alignment is possible, but the output is not really nice. The second realization is how I'd do it; I don't think that the alignment is helpful, but rather that it's distracting.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newcommand{\im}{I}

\begin{document}

\begin{lemma}
For all\\[\topsep]
$\begin{alignedat}{4}
  \makebox[\leftmargini][r]{\upshape(a)\hspace{\labelsep}}
  && t,t' &\in c^+ &\text{ with } t &\leq t'\textup{: }
  & V_{tt'}(\im^\pm_c V_t) &= \im^\pm_c V_{t'}\textup{;}
  \\
  \makebox[\labelwidth][r]{\upshape(b)\hspace{\labelsep}}
  && r,r' &\in c^- &\text{ with } r &\leq r'\textup{: }
  & V_{rr'}(\im^\pm_c V_t) &\subseteq \im^\pm_c V_{t'}.
\end{alignedat}$
\end{lemma}

\begin{lemma}\mbox{}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\upshape(\alph*)]
\item For all $t,t'\in c^+$ with $t\leq t'$\textup{:}
      $V_{tt'}(\im^\pm_c V_t)=\im^\pm_c V_{t'}$\textup{;}
\item For all $r, r'\in c^-$ with $r\leq r'$\textup{:}
      $V_{rr'}(\im^\pm_c V_t)\subseteq \im^\pm_c V_{t'}$.
\end{enumerate}
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your code. However, the problem was not the alignment, but to produce the labels: What happens if I decide later that labels for enumerations should look different in the entire document?

Comment: @Bubaya A further reason for (1) defining with `enumitem` features a type of enumeration to be used in statements; (2) avoiding those alignments, which may be good in math displays, but usually aren't for running text.

Comment: I have improved my own attempt, but I'am afraid that I'm unable to get the spacing right.